# Adapter for Recyclerview and Cardview in Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

1. I have created a Default Navigation Drawer, In Navigation Drawer Activity Two tabs are created.
2. In tabs Fragment are created.
3. In one Fragment I want to create **Recyclerview and Cardview**. For that I create two layout in one I declaired Recyclerview in Another Cardview and it's item.One java Class create in which Items are initiliased, So my question is what is Adapter file and Fragment code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand about the concept of fragments & recyclerview. So refer below sites to understand them

1. About Fragments: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
2. About recyclerview: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Comment: Thanks,but if you have any simple example of recyclerview in fragment, then please share me, Thanks in advance